# Can a bundle isomorphism be extended by 0 to a homomorphism on a larger vector bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles

Let $X$ be a topological space, $H$ a separable Hilbert space and $E$ a vector bundle over $X$. Suppose $f \colon E \rightarrow X \times \mathbb{C}^n$ is a bundle isomorphism and $E$ is subbundle of a trivial bundle $X\times H$. Can $f$ be extended pointwise by $0$ (the extension $F$ is defined as $f$ on $E_x$ and $0$ on $(E_x)^\perp$) so that the extensions $F_x \colon H \rightarrow H$ form a family of linear maps that depends continuously on x?

Since $f$ is an isomorphism, $f_x \colon E_x \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is a continuous family of linear maps and since $E$ is a trivial vector bundle we can continuously choose a basis for $E_x$ to perform the extension, but I can not write a rigorous proof for it.

Comment: Sorry to ask, maybe I don’t see something but if $f$ is an isomorphism of bundles, is not $E$ a trivial bundle ?

Comment: It is, I just want to explicitly want to construct the extension.

Comment: Oh I see. Nice question :) maybe we could work with functional analysis for good extensions ?

Comment: "extend by $0$" is misleading. You should be more precise in stating your question.

Comment: I specified the extension part.

Comment: I think for your question it might be worthy to include what you mean by "$E$ is a subbundle of $X\times H$". I came across such a setting in the context of Bloch bundles for periodic Hamiltonians, but there the subbundles of $X\times H$ were given in terms of the spectral projections and an isomorphism were constructed afterwards.